# Pens percentage of unused

Tags: java

The statement says:

A pen manufacturer has automated quality control of its products. When a
pen meets the minimum requirements, the unit in charge of quality control writes the letter 'S', otherwise writes 'N' and when finalize writes 'F'. Consider that after each
these characters of the device introduces a "intro / enter." Write a program that calculates the
percentage of pens that have not met the minimum requirements of manufacture. Supposed
the device writes the data correctly. (Boligrafos.java).

I put this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Boligrafs {

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    String estat;
    int contador1 = 0, contador2 = 0;
    float percentatge;

    System.out.println("Introdueix un estat del boligraf");
    estat = sc.next();

    while (estat == "S" || estat == "N") {
      if (estat == "S"){
        System.out.println("Introdueix un estat del boligraf");
        estat = sc.next();
      }
      else if (estat == "N"){
        System.out.println("Introdueix un estat del boligraf");
        estat = sc.next();
        contador1 = contador1 + 1;
      }
    contador2 = contador2 + 1;
    }
    if (estat == "F") {
      System.out.println("Has finalitzat");
    }

    percentatge = 100 * contador1 / contador2;
    System.out.println("El percentatge es:"+percentatge+"%");

  }
}
```

I can't understand the error because i think my program is correct:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at Boligrafs.main(Boligrafs.java:32)

Comment: Is this your school assignment? :)

Comment: What did you provide as input? You might not enter the while loop, therefore contador2 will be 0 => division by 0.

Comment: i dont understand you say

Comment: Also consider using String.equals(String other) instead of == for the String comparison

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `==` to compare strings that you entered against strings that are hardcoded in your program. Replace all `==` by `.equals()` and the problem should be solved.

For example, replace `estat == "S"` by `estat.equals("S")`

Comment: I might be wrong, but == should work for his case, since he doesn't call a new String constructor.

Comment: The code `sc.next()` returns a new string every time. The `==` operator when applied to Strings returns true if and only if the memory address of the two strings is the same.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Mike Laren you use estat.equals("S") for String value comparison and for calculating percenatge put your calculaiton part code inside if else part as below.

```
if(contador1>0 && contador2>0)
 {
   percentatge = 100 * contador1 / contador2;
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("your error message");
   percentatge=0.0;
 }
```